# Instance assignment is null but still able to reference properties?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

thank you for reading my post. I am working on a combat script for a text game. I got it to work once while writing it but now getting the most bizarre error.

I am making two `Character` objects called `charA, charB`. I am taking my array of instantiated Character objects, and assigning two random indices to `charA, charB`. The Debug.Log is telling me that `characters[indexA]` is null, and thus `charA` is null, so my `combatEncounter()` function is throwing an exception, and yet `charA.Name` displays the name in the TMP component. All of the `charA` stats are showing properly in the UI, but the class instance itself is null. I have no idea how to fix this and I feel like I'm missing something vital.

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ButtonGenerateName : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GenerateName generatorName;
    private GenerateWord generatorWord;
    private GameController gc;
    private Character character;
    private Character charA;
    private Character charB;
    private BuildingBlocks bb;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantNameA;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantNameB;
    public TextMeshProUGUI storyPanel;

    public TextMeshProUGUI combatanthpA;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatanthpB;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantWpnA;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantWpnB;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantstrA;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantstrB;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantdexA;
    public TextMeshProUGUI combatantdexB;

    public int NumberOfCharacters = 20;

    public List<Character> characters = new List<Character>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        generatorName = GetComponent<GenerateName>();
        generatorWord = GetComponent<GenerateWord>();
        character = GetComponent<Character>();
        bb = GetComponent<BuildingBlocks>();
        // Initialize GameController
        gc = GetComponent<GameController>();

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCharacters; i++) 
        {
            if (generatorName != null)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Loop `{i}` is entered!");
                /**
                * * NAME GENERATION:
                * * PREFIX => FIRST NAME => LAST NAME (DYNASTY) => SUFFIX => TITLE
                **/
                name = $"{bb.PREFIXES[UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, bb.PREFIXES.Count)]} {generatorName.nameGen(UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(1, 5))} {generatorName.nameGen(UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(1, 5))} {bb.SUFFIXES[UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, bb.SUFFIXES.Count)]} {bb.TITLES[UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, bb.TITLES.Count)]}";
            }
            Debug.Log("NameGen GameController: " + name);  
            Stats stats = new Stats() { Health = Random.Range(50, 150), Strength = Random.Range(3, 12), Agility = Random.Range(3, 12), Intelligence = Random.Range(3, 12) };
            Weapon weapon = new Weapon() { Name = bb.WEAPONS[UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, bb.WEAPONS.Count)], Damage = Random.Range(5, 120) };
            List<Trait> traits = new List<Trait>() { new Trait() { Name = "Brave", Description = "Never backs down from a fight" } };

            //GameObject characterGO = Instantiate(CharacterPrefab);
            character = new Character(name, stats, weapon, traits);
            characters.Add(character);
            Debug.Log("Character: " + character.Name);
            Debug.Log("Characters array: " + characters);
        }
        displayName();
        displayStory();
    }

    public void displayName()
    {
        // Check if the characters array has enough characters to choose from
        if (characters.Count < 2)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Not enough characters to select from.");
            return;
        }

        foreach (Character character in characters) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Character Name in list: " + character.Name);
        }

        // Select two different random indexes
        int indexA = UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, characters.Count - 1);
        int indexB;
        do
        {
            indexB = UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, characters.Count - 1);
        } while (indexA == indexB);

        Debug.Log("IndexA: " + indexA + ", IndexB: " + indexB);

        Debug.Log("characters[indexA]: " + characters[indexA]);
        Debug.Log("characters[indexB]: " + characters[indexB]);

        charA = characters[indexA];
        charB = characters[indexB];
        
        Debug.Log("CharA: " + charA);
        Debug.Log("CharB: " + charB);

        // Set the names to the TextMeshPro components
        combatantNameA.text = charA.Name;
        Debug.Log("Combatant A: " + combatantNameA.text);
        combatantNameB.text = charB.Name;
        Debug.Log("Combatant B: " + combatantNameB.text);

        // Set the HP to the TextMeshPro components
        combatanthpA.text = $"Health: {charA.CharacterStats.Health.ToString()}";
        combatanthpB.text = $"Health: {charB.CharacterStats.Health.ToString()}";

        // Set the Weapon name to the TextMeshPro components
        combatantWpnA.text = $"{charA.CharacterWeapon.Name}, DMG: ({charA.CharacterWeapon.Damage})";
        combatantWpnB.text = $"{charB.CharacterWeapon.Name}, DMG: ({charB.CharacterWeapon.Damage})";

        // Set the Strength to the TextMeshPro components
        combatantstrA.text = $"STR: {charA.CharacterStats.Strength.ToString()}";
        combatantstrB.text = $"STR: {charB.CharacterStats.Strength.ToString()}";

        // Set the Agility to the TextMeshPro components
        combatantdexA.text = $"DEX: {charA.CharacterStats.Agility.ToString()}";
        combatantdexB.text = $"DEX: {charB.CharacterStats.Agility.ToString()}";

    }

    public void displayStory()
    {
        /**
        * * STORY GENERATION:
        * * {COMBATANT A} met {COMBATANT B}
        * * AT THE {PLACE} OF {wordGen()}
        * * {whatHappened}
        **/
        string randomPlace = bb.PLACES[UtilityFunctions.GetRandomInt(0, bb.PLACES.Count)];
        string randomPlaceName = generatorWord.wordGen(10);
        string paragraph = "";
        string whatHappened = "";
        if(charA != null && charB != null)
        {
            whatHappened = combatEncounter(charA, charB);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("charA or charB is null, cannot call combatEncounter.");
        }

        paragraph += $"Once upon a time...\n\n{combatantNameA.text}\n met\n {combatantNameB.text}\n in battle at the {randomPlace} of {UtilityFunctions.CapitalizeFirstLetter(randomPlaceName)}.\n\n\n{whatHappened}";
        storyPanel.text = paragraph;
    }

    private string combatEncounter(Character A, Character B)
    {
        if(A == null || B == null) 
        {
            Debug.Log("A: " + A);
            Debug.Log("B: " + B);
            Debug.LogError("One or both of the characters are null.");

            return "";
        }

        string whatHappened = "";
        string turn = "";
        int damageA;
        int damageB;
        int hpA;
        int hpB;

        damageA = A.CharacterWeapon.Damage;
        damageB = B.CharacterWeapon.Damage;
        hpA = A.CharacterStats.Health;
        hpB = B.CharacterStats.Health;
        
        while (hpA > 0 && hpB > 0)
        {
            turn += $"{A.Name} attacked {B.Name} with a {A.CharacterWeapon.Name} for {damageA} damage.\n{B.name} had {hpB} health left.\n";
            hpA -= damageB;
            turn += $"{B.Name} attacked ${A.Name} with a {B.CharacterWeapon.Name} for {damageB} damage.\n{A.name} had {hpA} health left.\n";
            hpB -= damageA;
            whatHappened += $"{turn}\n\n";
            
        }
        Debug.Log("What happened: " + whatHappened);
        return whatHappened;
    }
}
```

Here is my log showing that charA and characters[indexA] are both null, and yet charA.Name ("CombatantA") is logging fine:
[image: Here is my log showing that charA and characters[indexA] are both null, and yet charA.Name ("CombatantA") is logging fine.]

EDIT: Adding my Character type implementation, if that helps.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Stats
{
    public int Health;
    public int Strength;
    public int Agility;
    public int Intelligence;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Weapon
{
    public string Name;
    public int Damage;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Trait
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
}

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Stats CharacterStats { get; set; }
    public Weapon CharacterWeapon { get; set; }
    public List<Trait> CharacterTraits { get; set; }

    public Character(string name, Stats stats, Weapon weapon, List<Trait> traits) 
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.CharacterStats = stats;
        this.CharacterWeapon = weapon;
        this.CharacterTraits = traits;
    }
   

}
```

Comment: Look at the implementation of `Character` type. 
It might override the `ToString` and `Equals` functions, which is causing this curious behaviour, whereby `ToString` returns `null` and `Equals(null)` returns true, despite object reference having an assignment.

Comment: @PaulG My ```Character``` type doesn't have any functions that would override ```ToString```. It just has 4 member classes for ```Stats```, ```Weapon```, etc. Will edit my post with the ```Character``` type.

Comment: but `MonoBehaviour` has! You should never have a constructor for a `MonoBehaviour` nor use `new` to create instance! They are instantiated and managed by the Unity Engine on `c++` level! Your `c#` script is just an API layer on top of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably happening because `Character` extends `MonoBehaviour`. Unity has it's own equality override for it's own objects (like `MonoBehaviours`, `GameObjects` and other things) which can say things are equal to `null` in scenarios where normal C# wouldn't (check out this article for more info about that: https://matheusamazonas.net/blog/2020/04/01/null-check-and-equality-in-unity/). It's a bit annoying and confusing but they had their reasons for it.

It doesn't look like you're attaching the `Character` objects to any `GameObject`s, and you are instantiating them with the `new` keyword rather than  something like `obj.AddComponent<Character>();`, so I assume that internally Unity is getting confused because the created `Character` behaviours aren't attached to any object, so their custom equality operator is saying it's `null`, even though it's not actually null.

I haven't tested it, but I think if you change `Character` to not extend `MonoBehaviour` then it will fix this issue.

Alternatively, if you want to keep it as a `MonoBehaviour`, you could keep it as-is but instantiate it by attaching it to an object by using `obj.AddComponent<Character>()` instead of `new Character()`.

Also, I am surprised your code runs without throwing errors earlier, as normally trying to create a `MonoBehaviour` instance using `new` causes an error (from what I've seen, anyway).

Comment: Thank you, I solved my issue by changing ```Character``` to a ```<ScriptableObject>```. Appreciate your help.